# Repeating SwiftUI animation gets choppy over time

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I've developed a repeating animation that starts out silky smooth but starts to get quite choppy after 10 or 20 seconds doing nothing else on my device. This is the entire code for the view (it is set as the content view of a single view app):

```
import SwiftUI

struct MovingCirclesView: View {
    @State var animationPercent: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MovingCircle(animationPercent: $animationPercent, size: 300, movementRadius: 100, startAngle: 0)
                .offset(x: -200, y: -200)

            MovingCircle(animationPercent: $animationPercent, size: 400, movementRadius: 120, startAngle: .pi * 3/4)
                .offset(x: 50, y: 300)

            MovingCircle(animationPercent: $animationPercent, size: 350, movementRadius: 200, startAngle: .pi * 5/4)
                .offset(x: 10, y: 30)

            MovingCircle(animationPercent: $animationPercent, size: 230, movementRadius: 80, startAngle: .pi * 1/2)
                .offset(x: 220, y: -300)

            MovingCircle(animationPercent: $animationPercent, size: 230, movementRadius: 150, startAngle: .pi)
                .offset(x: 220, y: 100)
        }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 30).repeatForever(autoreverses: false))
            .onAppear() { self.animationPercent = 1 }
    }

    private struct MovingCircle: View, Animatable {
        @Binding var animationPercent: Double

        let size: CGFloat
        let movementRadius: CGFloat
        let startAngle: Double

        var body: some View {
            Circle()
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .opacity(0.1)
                .offset(angle: .radians(.pi * 2 * self.animationPercent + self.startAngle), radius: self.movementRadius)
        }
    }
}

struct MovingCirclesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MovingCirclesView()
            .background(Color.black)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct AngularOffset: AnimatableModifier {
    var angle: Angle
    var radius: CGFloat

    var animatableData: AnimatablePair<Double, CGFloat> {
        get {
            return AnimatablePair(angle.radians, radius)
        }
        set {
            self.angle = .radians(newValue.first)
            self.radius = newValue.second
        }
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.offset(CGSize(
            width: CGFloat(cos(self.angle.radians)) * self.radius,
            height: CGFloat(sin(self.angle.radians)) * self.radius
        ))
    }
}
extension View {
    func offset(angle: Angle, radius: CGFloat) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: AngularOffset(angle: angle, radius: radius))
    }
}
```

The general idea is that there are a series of semi-transparent circles slowly moving in circles. I'm concerned this will not be worth the energy usage and was planning to profile anyway, but to my surprise, the animation seems to get bogged down rather quickly. I profiled it on an iPhone X and I don't see any increase in CPU usage nor Memory usage over time as the animation gets more and more choppy.

Does anyone have an idea of why the animation gets choppy? Anything I can do to fix that or do I have to throw out this idea?

Comment: Not compilable due to missed `.offset(angle:` modifier.

Comment: @Asperi whoops, sorry, I forgot that I used that modifier. I updated my post to include that modifier code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update: Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

As on now it seems `drawingGroup` does not have such positive effect as was before, because with used `.animation(.., value:)` animation works properly and with low resource consumption.

[image: demo]

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestForDrawingGroupOnAnimation.swift)

#### Original

Here is a solution - activating Metal by using `.drawingGroup` and using explicit animation.

Works fine with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 - tested during 5 mins, CPU load 4-5%

```
ZStack {

   // ..  circles here

}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.drawingGroup()
.onAppear() {
    withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 30).repeatForever(autoreverses: false)) {
        self.animationPercent = 1
    }
}
```

*Note: findings - it looks like implicit animation recreates update stack in this case again and again, so they multiplied, but explicit animation activated only once.*

Comment: Interesting, this did fix the issue when it was the primary view! I definitely have to learn more about the inner workings of SwiftUI. Unfortunately, the animation breaks when I embed this view in a more complex hierarchy. It seems to follow a parent animation (goes very quickly and only once). Any ideas on how to fix that? (I tried wrapping it in another `ZStack with .animation(nil)` and calling withAnimation after a delay)

Comment: Turns out it was because I was explicitly setting an animation on the view itself within the other view hierarchy. Luckily that explicit animation doesn't seem to be necessary so I was able to just remove it and solve the problem.

Comment: @drewag I'm experiencing the same issue. I tried changing implicit animation to explicit animation without luck. Would you please explain a little more specific how did you solve this issue? "Luckily that explicit animation doesn't seem to be necessary so I was able to just remove it and solve the problem" What does this mean?